# Has anybody seen this after starting a new Imperial Level construction?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Earlier today I started construction of a second Imperial Level (I had another under construction already). I just noticed that the title is different than normal.

Specifically, I'm looking at why the second Imperial Level is called "Food", when it's clearly an Imperial Level (and specifically, that one is either Blast Doors or Droid Works).

[image: Food level where Imperial Level should be]

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Answer derived from previous comments (now deleted):</sub>

---

This is generally just a display bug, the level is actually an Imperial Level despite the name.

You should try closing the game and reopening it. This often fixes similar display issues.